# Magento 2: catalog_product_save_after only for new products?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, catalog

Ive made an observer for the `catalog_product_save_after` event, but I want to only fire it when a new product is added to the catalog.

I did the same for the `sales_order_save_after` event and just added this code:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

if($order->getState() == 'new') {
    $this->shipment->write($order);
}
```

Is there an equivalent to this when making a new product?

I tried with `catalog_product_new_action` but didnt get any product data then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check event observer in `$productobject->getId()` is already exist or not if not exist then consider it's new one.. and use `catalog_product_save_before`

Comment: Didnt think about doing it that way! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, this is the code I ended up using:

Like @Himanshu said, use the `catalog_product_save_before` event for your observer.

```
class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $productExists = true;

        try {
            //load product with sku since new products dont have an id yet
            $isExists = $this->productRepository->get($product->getSku());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            $productExists = false;
        }

        if($productExists == false) {
            $this->article->writeArt($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check original data of the product in `catalog_product_save_after`, if sku is empty/blank,then current product is new.

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

if (empty($product->getOrigData('sku'))) {
 //this is the new product
```

Tested in Magento 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Event name catalog_product_save_after

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
    //Product created
}else{
    //Product updated
}
```